# Get id of sent mail

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently using [msgraph-sdk-php](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php) and when I hit the [/me/sendMail](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_sendmail) it doesn't return any information (which the graph API doc states already).

The thing is I need to know the internetMessageId or the Id of the sent message because I use a VSTO Outlook Addin, that needs that information in order to keep track  of all sent mails, regardless if it is sent from Outlook client or Graph API.

What i've tried so far is [creating a Draft message](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_messages) which would then give me back the message information created (including Id, InternetMessageId), and I'd use [/me/messages/{id}/send](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_send) to send it.

However, the internetMessageId of the sent mail is not the same as the one created in the Draft Folder which I assume is normal since it's in a different folder.

And that's where I'm stuck atm.

Comment: I have explained a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861188/in-outlook-graph-api-the-message-id-appears-to-change-after-calling-send-on-a-d/58765888#58765888

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, well kinda.

What i actually do is Create the draft message using the following route [/me/mailFolders/SentItems/messages](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_messages) and then I can simply send it using it's Id, and since the message is not moved upon send, it still has the same InternetMessageId.

However i have an issue. When the mail is sent, on the Outlook Desktop Client, the message doesn't have any Internet Headers (headers which would contain InternetMessageId). I expected this to be present all the time, but apparently for outgoing mails it doesn't get added...

So I have no way of finding this mail in Outlook VSTO since when i open this same mail in Sent Folder, it has no headers at all.

Comment: As a workaround to this problem, I had to add SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty to my message in order the add the InternetMessageId to sent items. This way i can retrieve it in outlook and do my business logic. Feels hackish, but couldn't find another way. As an example of Extended Properties, i used [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/dev/tests/Functional/ContactTest.php)